# Random Sample of rows from an R dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

Suppose I have a dataset with `(90,000 x 17)` i.e. `(n x p)` where `n` is the `number of observations` and `p` is the `number of variables` and I would like to take a random sample of `20%` of rows from my whole dataset how can this be done in R?

After taking a random sample I will be performing cluster analysis accordingly.

I had tried using other questions to answer my question but they were inconclusive because it was not giving me what I needed.

Comment: `sample()` with repeated sampling could help

Comment: `df[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)*0.2),]`

Comment: Remember to fix seed `set.seed(1492)` (or any number) in order to obtain reproducibility of your sample!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `sample_frac` from `dplyr`, here is an example with the database iris

```
 library(dplyr)
 #data(iris)
 sample20 <- iris %>% sample_frac(0.2)
```